# ¿cual es el porque de este error en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: java, double, scanner

Estoy aprendiendo a programar por mi cuenta a través de manuales pdf, mi pregunta es por que me sale un error y no me devuelve el numero máximo cuando ingreso números con decimales este es el código y el error también lo coloco aquí por que no se que quiere decir

```
package byJoel;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        //crea un objeto Scanner para introducir datos desde la ventana de comandos
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        //pide y recibe como entrada tres valores de punto flotante
        System.out.print("Escriba tres valores de punto flotante, separados por espacios: ");
        double numero1 = entrada.nextDouble();
        double numero2 = entrada.nextDouble();
        double numero3 = entrada.nextDouble();

        //determina el valor maximo
       // double resultado = Maximo(numero1,numero2,numero3);

        //Imprime el valor Maximo
        System.out.println("El maximo de los tres es: "+ Maximo(numero1, numero2, numero3));
    }

    //creamos un método que devuelve el máximo de sus tres parametros double
    public static double Maximo(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double ValorMax = x; // asume que x es el mayor para empezar"

        if (y > ValorMax)
            ValorMax = y;
        if (z > ValorMax)
            ValorMax = z;

        return ValorMax;
    }
}
```

ERROR QUE ME SALE AL INGRESAR NUMERO DE PUNTO FLOTANTE

```
Escriba tres valores de punto flotante, separados por espacios: 5.22 12.4 8.32
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
>   at byJoel.Main.main(Main.java:15)
> ```

Comment: Cabe resaltar que la linea 15 es double numero1 = entrada.nextDouble();

Comment: Has probado a utilizar la coma como separador de los decimales? es decir, 5,22 12,4 8,32 y no 5.22 12.4 8.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes especificar una configuración regional para tu objeto Scanner de la siguiente forma:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Según la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers) :

> An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the
>   standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A
>   scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the
>   Locale.getDefault() method; it may be changed via the
>   useLocale(java.util.Locale) method
>   The localized formats are defined in terms of the following
>   parameters, which for a particular locale are taken from that locale's
>   DecimalFormat object, df, and its and DecimalFormatSymbols object,
>   dfs.

Traducción:

> Una instancia de esta clase es capaz de escanear números en 
>   formatos estándar, así como en los formatos de la configuración regional del escáner. Un
>   escenario inicial del escáner es el valor devuelto por el
>   método Locale.getDefault (); Puede cambiarse a través del
>   método useLocale(java.util.Locale) 
>  
>   Los formatos localizados se definen en términos de los siguientes
>   parámetros, que para una localidad particular se toman de la configuración regional
>   del objeto DecimalFormat, df, y su objeto DecimalFormatSymbols,
>   Dfs.

Por lo tanto, tu configuración regional predeterminada utiliza un `DecimalFormat` que espera una coma como un delimitador decimal en lugar de un punto.

Respuesta extraída de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150679/3683321)